# ng-type / show-password directive on `<input>` element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We can use data-binding on input elements like this:

```
<input type="{{ showPassword ? 'text' : 'password' }}" name="password">
```

But this has similar problems as using data-binding on a `href` attribute ([see ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)). This way there is an input element in the dom with the type `{{ showPassword ? 'text' : 'password' }}` until angular loads. It looks convenient to have an `ngType` directive much like `ngHref`, what could be used this way:

```
<input type="password" ng-type="{{ showPassword ? 'text' : 'password' }}" name="password">
```

Is there any other way to do it? Do I have to implement this `ngType` thing?

Comment: Do you have to use it with standard `<input>`? A directive wrapping the two variant of the input is doable.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I wonder if ng-model will work on that too

Comment: Yes, certainly. It needs a custom control to use `ng-model` on the outer directive, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/2438/directives-using-ngmodelcontroller#t=201608311344143021119) for how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Custom directive that changes the `<input>` type:

To show or hide the password use a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```
app.directive("showPassword", function() { 
    return function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.showPassword, function(newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                elem.attr("type", "text");
            } else {
                elem.attr("type", "password");
            };
        });
    };
});
```

### Usage

```
 <input type=password show-password="showPassword" 
        ng-model="thePassword">
```

The `show-password` directive watches the defined scope variable and changes the input to `type=text` when truthy and back to `type=password` when falsey.

## [The DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e1vm6u8r/)

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.directive("showPassword", function() { 
    return function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.showPassword, function(newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                elem.attr("type", "text");
            } else {
                elem.attr("type", "password");
            };
        });
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>

    <button ng-click="showPassword = true">Show Password</button><br>
    <button ng-click="showPassword = false">Hide Password</button><br>
    
    <input type=password show-password="showPassword" 
           ng-model="thePassword">
    <hr>
    PASSWORD == {{thePassword}}
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution that does not involve manipulating dom from the controller. I like the idea of not using `ng-type` but a `show-password` so it is impossible to set it to `date` or `number` accidentally from the controller.