# AngularJs - show-hide password on click event using directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one input field for password and one button with that input field
now, if type of input field is **password**i.e `type="password"`,  then on click of that button it should become **text** i.e `type="text"`
if again I click on the same button it should change `type="password"`

Means it should toggle the `value` of type of input element

I have done this using controller, It's working fine with controller. below is the working code using controller

But instead of controller if i want to use directive then how to handle this toggle condition using directive

*purpose - I want to use this functionality on multiple input elements*

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
   <label>Password</label>
   <input type="{{inputType}}" class="form-control" ng-model="password" />
   <span ng-click="show()">show</span>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.inputType = 'password';

$scope.show = function() {
  if ($scope.inputType === 'password') {
     $scope.inputType = !$scope.inputType;
     $scope.inputType = 'text';
  } else {
     $scope.inputType = !$scope.inputType;
     $scope.inputType = 'password';
  }
}
```

I tried using Directive - Below is my trial code
I am not getting how to change the type of `<input />` element using directive

**Directive**

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       console.log(attrs.type);
       attrs.type = 'password'

      // how to call this below code on click event or on click of <span>  
         which I am using for password

       if (attrs.type === 'password') {
          attrs.type = !attrs.type;
          attrs.type = 'text';
       } else {
          attrs.type = !attrs.type.inputType;
          attrs.type = 'password';
       }
    }
})
```

**HTML Using Directive**

```
<div class="input-group">
   <label>Password</label>
   <input my-dir type="" class="form-control" ng-model="password" />
   <span ng-click="show()">show</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want someone to create a directive for you?

Comment: @Tuhin I have added my trial directive code - I am not getting how to change type using directive

Comment: there is no built-in directive for this. You need to write a custom directive. Look into this. You might get some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247705/ng-type-show-password-directive-on-input-element-in-angularjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ng-attr-type directive for dynamically change the input type. For example:

```
<input ng-attr-type="{{ isPassword ? 'password' : 'text' }}">
```

you can change the value of `isPassword`  to the click event and make it toggle.

Using directive

```
.directive('isPassword', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'A', 
    scope: {
      isPassword: '=isPassword'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.$watch('isPassword', function(a, b){
         element.attr('type', a ? 'password' : 'text')
       })
    }
  }
});

<input is-password="checkPassword" placeholder="Put your password" />

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkPassword" />
```

update on button click

```
<button ng-click="checkPassword=!checkPassword">click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, But I have one doubt - where is click event ? so that on click of that button it should toggle the condition for password

Comment: I have updated my answer for toggling the state for password type or u can toggle it from controller using click event on any element

Comment: This is working only for `<input type="checkbox" />` not on button. but I want this condition on click of button. like:- instead of checkbox it should work on click of button, in that case how to achieve this ?

Comment: Thanks, its working fine. by default to hide password I have added `ng-init="checkPassword = true"` so default it is hiding my password and only on click of button it will show

Answer (score 2):

This is what the following directive does when added to the input element.

1. It appends a span element "Show me" with `ng-click=show()` event attached to it.
2. `scope: true` enables an isolated scope for the directive. This makes sure the function `show()` is unique for each directive.
3. When clicked on "Show me", the directive changes the input type of that element.

Hope this helps.

[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/x8ut1vn7/)

Comment: Thanks, @gilango This one is working fine for me but if I am using multiple directives on same `<input />` element that time I am getting error for isolated scope. and if I remove `scope=true` then above dierective is not working properly, can you please guide me how to handle isolated scope in this scenario

Comment: That means your other directive is also having an isolated scope. 2 directives used in the same element cannot have isolated scope of their own. Not sure how to build this directive without an isolated scope because of show method. Maybe you can combine both directives as single directive?