# Set an invalid date string HTML5 date input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date

I'm wondering if it is possible to set an invalid date string to an HTML5 date input after some JS check, for example "Today" instead of displaying XX-XX-XXXX date?

Note that I'm working with angular-1.6 that uses it's built-in directive that makes this hack harder to realize.

```
<input id="dateNative"
   type="date"
   ng-model="date.selectedDate"
   min="{{minDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">


function Controller($scope, $log, $element, $document) {
  $scope.date = {};
  $scope.minDate = new Date();

  this.$postLink = () => {
    this.dateCtrl = angular.element($document[0].getElementById('dateNative')).controller('ngModel');
    this.dateCtrl.$parsers.unshift(date => {
      if (moment(new Date()).isSame(date, 'day')) {
        return 'Immediately';
      }
      return date;
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the input `type` to text

```
this.dateCtrl.$parsers.unshift(date => {
  if (moment(new Date()).isSame(date, 'day')) {
    $element[0].type = 'text';
    return 'Immediately';
  }
  $element[0].type = 'date';
  return date;
});
```

Comment: Like this I will lose the input date, specially the mobile experience the user will enter date manually ...

Comment: Well can't have it both ways...invalid value and keep `date` type. Will have to think of another way to do it then. Perhaps using `<label for="dateNative">`

Comment: Thank you, but this is not suitable for me, the UI team won't accept to add label to display selected date :D

Comment: Idea was only use the label for invalid values (over top input).... otherwise it won't be visible

Answer (score 1):

The element can use [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) to define the input type

```
<input id="dateNative"
   type="{{date.type}}"
   ng-model="date.selectedDate"
   min="{{minDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" />
```

```
$scope.date.type = "text";
$scope.date.selectedDate = "Immediately";
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, but it just need some work to make it more dynamic :)

Comment: I recommend that dynamic type changing be done inside a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that is attached to the `<input>` element. Avoid doing DOM manipulation in a view controller.

Comment: For an example of a directive that changes an `<input>` type, see [show-password directive on `<input>` element in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39258609/5535245).